# possible module in play framework (1.2.4 version)

Tags: module, playframework, jodatime, playframework-1.x

I wonder if any of you out there working with the Play Framework, has came across a module that is displaying a timestamp for a, let's say as an example, a blogpost , in the form (once again an example) "Yesterday at 11:23" and so on. Although using joda time (builtin in Play Framework), i have actually managed to build something working in this direction.

Still just curious if there exists a module...

Sinc. Kalle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not a module, but a JavaExtension for the Date object called `since()`. Its part of core.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/javaextensions#date

Its not exact, but close. To create exactly this functionality should be a simple JavaExtension.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, appears to be what i was after.